# Better to use CanExecute or a converter?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a dashboard application that uses a frame to switch pages on a window. For obvious reasons, I'm disabling buttons like 'Home' etc. when the user is on the login page.

Currently I'm using a converter to bind the `IsEnabled` property of my buttons to whether the current page is the login page like so:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Page), typeof(bool))]
public class IsNotLoginPageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(value is Login);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Converter cannot convert back.");
    }
}

IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CurrentPage, Converter={StaticResource IsLoginPage}}"
```

but I'm wondering if it is in someway better to instead bind the commands to Can Executes instead, like so:

```
bool isNotLoginPage()
{
    return !(CurrentPage is Login);
}

RelayCommand home;
public ICommand Home
{
    get { return home ?? (home = new RelayCommand(homeExecute, isNotLoginPage)); }
}
void homeExecute()
{
    Switcher.Switch(new MainPage());
}
```

I can see that it would be less code but are they any other advantages (e.g. overhead) to doing this either way? I haven't been able to find anything online that compares the two methods.

Comment: I prefer to use `CanExecute` over a converter. It keeps your code in the same location as your command so its easy to find/edit/debug/etc in the future, and gives you the option to manually raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event from the ViewModel if ever needed. Also if you ever want to execute the command from somewhere else (a button click, context menu, etc), the CanExecute is already setup for easy access.

Comment: Thinking about it, I probably will use CanExecute`. I'm just wondering if there is something I'm not thinking about that makes this method 'worse'